# Wrong result, when using FFTW only do forward FFT and inverse FFT or FFTW with ESTIMATE and MEASURE?

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, fftw

When using [FFTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFTW), I only do forward [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) and then inverse FFT for [array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_(data_structure)), but I get a **wrong result** when the `length` of FFT has specific value, for example `length==84`.

Code example:

```cpp
int main() {
  const int rows = 84;
  fftw_complex *in = (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * rows);
  memset(in, 0, sizeof(fftw_complex) * rows);
  in[0][0] = in[1][0] = in[2][0] = 1.0;
  fftw_plan plan_fft  = fftw_plan_dft_1d(rows, in, in, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  fftw_plan plan_ifft = fftw_plan_dft_1d(rows, in, in, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  fftw_execute(plan_fft);
  fftw_execute(plan_ifft);
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    std::cout << in[i][0] / rows << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

As shown in the above code, the **wanted result** is:

```
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ... 0 0
```

ut the **actual result** is:

```
1 0.999068 0.996277 0.991643 1.65826e-17 -1.22373e-17 -3.68811e-17 -1.88926e-17 -9.12265e-18 3.45078e-17 2.30831e-17 4.92708e-17 4.17271e-17 2.61058e-17 1.60247e-17 -0.0100873 -0.0187201 -0.0258501 -1.0593e-17 -2.53148e-17 2.5538e-17 2.24688e-17 1.60449e-17 3.79879e-17 1.26333e-17 2.47918e-17 3.51694e-17 -4.52437e-18 -4.57848e-18 0.0105533 0.0205816 0.0300288 3.14536e-18 -1.80787e-17 9.25439e-18 1.71057e-18 6.38559e-18 2.79698e-17 -2.29849e-17 5.09812e-18 1.19693e-17 6.06313e-19 0 -8.45884e-17 8.45884e-17 0 -2.5447e-18 -1.02155e-17 3.16047e-17 2.33067e-17 1.64392e-17 2.23584e-17 -3.89767e-18 1.83711e-17 1.46201e-17 -7.95307e-18 4.57848e-18 -0.0110194 -0.0224432 -0.0342075 -6.40249e-18 -2.12686e-17 3.15629e-17 9.25186e-18 1.97198e-17 6.53782e-18 -2.50131e-18 -5.43689e-17 6.60354e-18 1.12718e-17 -1.60247e-17 0.0114854 0.0243047 0.0383862 -2.99259e-17 5.53942e-17 1.82227e-17 2.5596e-17 -1.88591e-18 -3.41998e-17 -4.34999e-18 -4.31629e-17 -4.66482e-17 -2.55064e-17
```

When I change the flag value of the FFT from `FFTW_ESTIMATE` to `FFTW_MEASURE`, the result is correct.

Why does this happen? I've been confused on this for a long time, can anyone help me?

Only when the FFT `length` is valued, for instance, to `84`, it will produce such an error, and other values are normal again, such as `95`.

Comment: Have you noticed the actual numbers are very close to your desired ouput? So you get rounding/approximatin errors because you ask FFTW to use FFTW_ESTIMATE (which will not surprisingly give you an approximation)

Comment: With `FFT_MEASURE`, a faster algorithm is looked for, for the given size. This leads to less operations and then sometimes to less rounding errors.

Comment: @Damien I think the algorithm used is faster because it will either not use full numerical error propagation or just uses lest steps (e.g. in Taylor series for sin/cos), resulting in less precise results.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Generally, in FFT, tables are used to the sin/cos. And OP get a better result with the faster algorithm ...

Comment: @Damien ah ok, its been a long long long time since I used FFTW so I forgot the impl details. So Iwas answering from numerical math experiences.  ;)

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer I know that there will be some rounding errors. For example, except for the first three numbers in the correct result, the others are very small numbers close to 0. But please pay attention to the fourth value in the wrong result, it should be very close to 0 , but now it is very close to 1(0.991643), which is a very obvious error.

Answer (score 0):

It's using floating point math so it's unlikely going to give to *exacly* `0` or `1`, but rather some value *pretty close* to it.

You can also experiment with other [planner flags](https://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Planner-Flags.html):

- `FFTW_ESTIMATE` specifies that, instead of actual measurements of different algorithms, a simple heuristic is used to pick a (probably sub-optimal) plan quickly. With this flag, the input/output arrays are not overwritten during planning.
- `FFTW_MEASURE` tells FFTW to find an optimized plan by actually computing several FFTs and measuring their execution time. Depending on your machine, this can take some time (often a few seconds). `FFTW_MEASURE` is the default planning option.
- `FFTW_PATIENT` is like `FFTW_MEASURE`, but considers a wider range of algorithms and often produces a “more optimal” plan (especially for large transforms), but at the expense of several times longer planning time (especially for large transforms).
- `FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE` is like `FFTW_PATIENT`, but considers an even wider range of algorithms, including many that we think are unlikely to be fast, to produce the most optimal plan but with a substantially increased planning time.
- `FFTW_WISDOM_ONLY` is a special planning mode in which the plan is only created if wisdom is available for the given problem, and otherwise a NULL plan is returned. This can be combined with other flags, e.g. `FFTW_WISDOM_ONLY | FFTW_PATIENT` creates a plan only if wisdom is available that was created in `FFTW_PATIENT` or `FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE` mode. The `FFTW_WISDOM_ONLY` flag is intended for users who need to detect whether wisdom is available; for example, if wisdom is not available one may wish to allocate new arrays for planning so that user data is not overwritten.

You can also use `std::fixed` to make it easier to see that the result is close to your wanted result more easily.

Also, since you are using C++, use `std::vector<std::complex<double>>` as a container instead of `fftw_malloc` and only convert to `fftw_complex` when interacting with the FFTW library. That way you don't have to manually free the allocated memory - or have memory leaks like your current program has.

Rewritten to use a C++ container, a different planner flag and `std::fixed`:

```cpp
#include <fftw3.h>

#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// helpers to interact with C functions:
template<class T>
using two = T[2];

template<class T>
two<T>* to_c(std::complex<T>* in) {
    return reinterpret_cast<two<T>*>(in);
}

template<class T>
two<T>& to_c(std::complex<T>& in) {
    return reinterpret_cast<two<T>&>(in);
}
// ---------------------------------------

int main() {
    constexpr unsigned rows = 84;
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> in(rows);

    fftw_plan plan_fft = fftw_plan_dft_1d(
        rows, to_c(in.data()), to_c(in.data()), FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);
    fftw_plan plan_ifft = fftw_plan_dft_1d(
        rows, to_c(in.data()), to_c(in.data()), FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);

    to_c(in[0])[0] = to_c(in[1])[0] = to_c(in[2])[0] = 1.0;
    // or, the C++ way:
    //in[0].real(1.0);
    //in[1].real(1.0);
    //in[2].real(1.0);

    fftw_execute(plan_fft);
    fftw_execute(plan_ifft);

    std::cout << std::fixed;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        std::cout << in[i].real() / rows << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that there will be some rounding errors. For example, except for the first three numbers in the correct result, the others are very small numbers close to 0. But please pay attention to the fourth value in the wrong result, it should be very close to 0 , but now it is very close to 1(0.991643), which is a very obvious error.

Comment: In addition, memory leaks will not have a negative impact on this program, because the program ends quickly, and the operating system will reclaim the resources of this process.

Comment: @hjzhao The fourth value printed by the program above is `-0.000000`. All the rest of the values are either `-0.000000` or `0.000000`. Is that wrong? Only the three first are `1.000000`.

Regarding memory leaks: Sure, but it also doesn't hurt to do proper memory management from the start.

Comment: Yes, your program is correct, because you changed the flag to FFTW_MEASURE. But according to my original code, the FFT flag I used is FFTW_ESTIMATE, and the fourth number is 0.991643, not close to 0. I want to know why this behavior occurs.

Comment: @hjzhao I think you've must have logged the wrong results. The fourth value _your_ program prints for me is `-1.36655e-17` - or in `std::fixed` mode, `-0.000000`.

Comment: I checked my output again. I modify your code only where the plan is constructed.
`fftw_plan plan_fft = fftw_plan_dft_1d(rows, to_c(in.data()), to_c(in.data()), FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_plan plan_ifft = fftw_plan_dft_1d(rows, to_c(in.data()), to_c(in.data()), FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);`
FFT flag from `FFTW_MEASURE` to `FFTW_ESTIMATE`. The result is 1.000000 0.999068 0.996277 `0.991643` 0.0  ... 0.0 0.010553 0.020582 0.030029 0.0 ... 0.0 -0.011019 -0.022443 -0.034207 -0.0 ... 0.0 0.011485 0.024305 0.038386 -0.0 ... 0.0
The fourth value still is `0.991643`.

Comment: @hjzhao How exactly are you compiling the program? Are you using any "fast math" options? I don't expect them to produce _that_ different results, but if you are using such options, try not doing that. What compiler and version are you using? What version of FFTW are you using? Your compiler and/or FFTW library may be broken and need to be reinstalled or upgraded.

Comment: `./configure --prefix=/home/Applications/fftw3.3.10 --enable-shared  --enable-threads --enable-openmp --enable-mpi --enable-sse2 --enable-avx512 --enable-generic-simd256 --enable-avx-128-fma` This is the configuration when I installed FFTW 3.3.10. 
`g++ ./fft.cpp -o fft -fopenmp -I /home/Applications/fftw3.3.10/include -L /home/Applications/fftw3.3.10/lib -lfftw3 && ./fft`. This is my command to compile and run the program. 
Will there be any negative effects of doing so?

Comment: @hjzhao No, those look fine. You could however try with only the `--prefix=...` and `--enable-shared` flags and then build your application without `-fopenmp` to rule those other options out.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much for your guidance, now I can output the correct result. Thank you very much.

Comment: @hjzhao Wow! I didn't actually expect that to help, but, cool that it did! You're welcome!

Comment: All options are valid except `--enable-generic-simd256`. When I don't use `--enable-generic-simd256`, I will get right.

Comment: @hjzhao Oh. There seems to have been bugs in an older version of FFTW w.r.t. single precision and maybe this is a similar issue? Perhaps you could [open an issue @ FFTW](https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3/issues) and provide the info about `--enable-generic-simd256` together with your little test program so they can verify it.